# Image in UITextField rightView not appearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have this code to add a 26 x 30 .png file into the right view of a UITextField.

```
//add button to address bar
//UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[refreshButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[refreshButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
refreshButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -16, 0, 0);
[refreshButton addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
addressBar.rightView = refreshButton;
addressBar.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
```

the button is touchable and calls the method that it should, but the image is not displayed.

any ideas? could it be that the image is too big for the text field? My text field is the standard size that I dragged into from IB, so I don't think that's it, but it's an idea.

the text field is 245 x 31

Comment: `refreshButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -16, 0, 0);` this really helped my problem, I add an UIButton with custom style. But the position is not correct. Thanks dude!

Comment: tip: with a large image (and therefore a large imageEdgeInset), you may find (as I did), UIControlEventTouchUpInside not firing even though when you touch the button it highlights properly.   Turns out I had offset the image to land outside the bounds of 'inside' the button.   Grudgingly overrode rightViewRectForBounds method in a UITextField subclass to give it the exact sizing for the UIButton I had placed in the rightView of the UITextfield, removed imageEdgeInsets, and now all works properly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried specifying a frame when initializing your UIButton instead of using the class method buttonWithType. I am guessing the textfield cannot determine the size of your button without it.

```
[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)]
```

Comment: In case you come here after I have left (after July 21st 2022)....The above answer means this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55800770/12306937

Answer (score 0):

Adding right or left view in textfiled should go before add text or hint for textfield, that was issue on my side